# openJPEG installation: $ make make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop

Tags: makefile, installation, windows-10, mingw-w64, jpeg2000

So.
Coming from

```
OpenJPEG installation
The build method maintained by OpenJPEG is CMake.
UNIX/LINUX - MacOS (terminal) - WINDOWS (cygwin, MinGW)
To build the library, type from source tree directory:`

    mkdir build
    cd build
    cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
    make
```

https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md

After properly getting `Cmake` to build, `mingw-get` to get `msys-make` (and also `msys 1.0`) to even have a proper response from `MingW64`, no matter what I do, I am stuck in the same error.
Downloaded first from the `openjpeg-v2.3.1-windowsx64` link which the above proceeding seems to do nothing, as there is no CMakeList file there, then from the 'Source Code' `openjpeg-2.3.1` which I can build from but that's it.
Can't make, can't install, can't use.

Considered 'source tree folder' the downloaded folder itself, the src folder inside of it and even a src folder of a IntelliJ project.

What am I missing?

```
PATH VARIABLE: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
%IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition%;
C:\Users\Ajna\Desktop\jar2app\jar2app\jar2app_basefiles;
C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;
C:\MinGW\bin;
C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-static\bin;
C:\msys\1.0\bin;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've spent quite a while with this myself today. Here's what worked for me.

1. Download the whole code folder (green download code button) from
   https://github.com/uclouvain/openjpeg
   The downloaded folder is called "openjpeg-master". Save it in your downloads folder.
2. Install MinGW from  [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/mingweclipse/mingw.html](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Epattis/common/handouts/mingweclipse/mingw.html)
3. Install msys from
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/msys-core/msys-1.0.11/MSYS-1.0.11.exe/download?use_mirror=altushost-swe
4. Open windows command line.
5. Navigate to the location of the "openjpeg-master" folder
   e.g.

```
cd C:\#insert_location_of_your_downloads_folder#\Downloads\openjpeg-master
```

To specify the use of MinGW makefiles on windows use the following command

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make
```

Answer (score 0):

The default for cmake on Windows is to use a Visual Studio generator: it generates project files for use with Visual Studio, not makefiles.

If you want it to generate makefiles you have to tell it specifically:

```
cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

You probably want to file an issue with the project and ask them to update their INSTALL file to have proper instructions.

Comment: Note, generally it can be a problem to change generators if there's an existing cmake configuration so you may have to delete the contents of the `build` directory you created before running that cmake command.

Comment: Also you probably wanted to use a `cmake` tag, rather than a `makefile` tag: for projects that use cmake they auto-generate makefiles and there's little need for anyone to wrangle makefiles directly.

Comment: `The default for cmake on Windows is to use a Visual Studio generator: it generates project files for use with Visual Studio, not makefiles.`

Yet as mentioned am I using IntelliJ, not Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment relates to what I said.  When you run cmake on Windows, it will always generate Visual Studio project files, unless you explicitly tell it otherwise.  The `cmake` command you quoted from the `INSTALL` file doesn't contain any explicit `-G` generator option so if that's the command you invoked then it's using the default for Windows, which you don't want.

Comment: I actually meant `CMakeList file`(sorry, friday late) which is only a quote from the error I was getting, not a command at all. And I am on windows, why would I not want it?

Comment: Because you said you're trying to use `make` to build your project.  Visual Studio doesn't use make, it has its own build system.  If you generate Visual Studio project files then you have to compile your project with Visual Studio, _not_ with `make`.  So, choose the one you want but you have to be consistent.  If you want to build with `make` you have to tell `cmake` to generate makefiles, you can't have it generate its default Visual Studio project files.

Comment: $ cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
(...)

Comment: That's a cmake problem, not related to `make`.  maybe you only installed the C compiler for GCC, not the C++ compiler?  I don't know much about MinGW or Windows at all.